# ubuntu failed to boot after removing /var/tmp

Tags: boot

I tried to delete the crash files but mistakenly I deleted /var/temp folder.
Then I deleted my crash files too, soon after that.
When I restarted my Ubuntu, the login screen froze
So I 'Alt+Ctr+F2' on my system, logged in, and did update and upgrade.
I assumed the problem was with grub so I eventually did grub update.
But now it has become worse, the Ubuntu fails to boot with some errors.
I am using 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the only problem is the missing directory, please recreate it:

using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> as you did before, enter the commands

```
sudo mkdir /var/tmp
sudo chmod 777 /var/tmp
sudo chmod o+t /var/tmp
```

Ensure that the listing of the directory lists 'root' as owner and group, and that the permissions are as shown below:

```
ls -ld /var/tmp
drwxrwxrwt 9 root root 4096 Dec 14 19:12 /var/tmp
```

then reboot the computer:  `sudo reboot`

Comment: I didn't got the chance to follow your guideline. I was in haste and did a quick install of ubuntu all over again as I had no files to loose doing so. Thank you, I think you will be of help to others.

Comment: You're welcome!